# Extracting month from date values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table on my opportunities won tab that has a date, the logger finds the dates just fine. But I want to use the month to categorize each input on the opportunities tab, regardless of day or year, into the summary tab *jan-dec*. I found `.getMonth()` but it says the error that it cannot find function `.getMonth()` in object. I am trying to get the object to be the current row (`var i`)

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var summary = ss.getSheetByName("Summary")
      var oppwon = ss.getSheetByName("Opportunities Won");
      var j = oppwon.getLastRow();

   for(var i =8;i<=j;i++) {
      var dates = oppwon.getRange(i,22).getValue();
      var tiers = oppwon.getRange(i,14).getValue();
      var month = dates.getMonth();

    Logger.log(dates.getMonth());
```

Comment: What type of data is in `dates`?  Is it a single Date object?

Comment: yes its just an input of a date  mm/dd/yy

Comment: That's not the same as a Date object.  It should look like this: "Wed Sep 11 2019 14:43:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" and its `typeof` should return `object`.  If it's anything else, `getMonth()` is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dates is just an input of a date `mm/dd/yy`, cast to `new Date()` before usage:

```
new Date(dates).getMonth();
```